# PyQt clicked.connect is connected automatically

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm currently implementing a model view architecture for my PyQt GUI. Here's a simpler, but representative version of my code at the moment (since mine is waaaay too long)

```
class Model(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.openDir = '/some/file/dir/'
    def openFile(self):
        openFileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File",self.loadDir,"AllFiles(*.*)")
        open = open(openFileName, 'r')
        ...

class View(QtGui.QWidget):
    def__init__(self):
    ...
    self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Open")
    ...
    self.button.clicked.connect(Model().openFile())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = View()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, the even if I haven't pressed the button, the signal is already emitted and the QFileDialog window comes up automatically.

---

Edit 1:

Because I ran into a new problem regarding the same subject, I have opened a new question for more input.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I see the issue.

```
self.button.clicked.connect(Model().openFile())
```

should be

```
self.button.clicked.connect(Model().openFile)
```

In the first instance, you're calling the openFile method and passing the return value to "connect".  In the the second, you're passing the method itself to "connect".

Comment: I tried it when I first got the error, but when I do say `Model().openFile`, I get a new error saying that 'Model' object has no attribute 'button'. So I tried making the 'self.button' 'Model.button' but that doesn't quite work either...

Comment: I think you might need to show more code for me to understand that exception.  Or at least the traceback.  It does not make sense with the code I see in your question.

Comment: I actually stopped getting the issue I stated above but am facing a new problem, and opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612877/pyqt-when-button-is-pressed-to-connect-to-a-method-of-different-class-code-nev. I'll try and elaborate more on the code and add more details.