# PyQt, when button is pressed to connect to a method of different class, code never exits __init__

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm currently implementing a model view architecture for my PyQt GUI. Here's a simpler, but representative version of my code at the moment.

```
class Model(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.openDir = '/some/file/dir/'
    def openFile(self):
        openFileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File",self.openDir,"AllFiles(*.*)")
        openFile = open(openFileName, 'r')
        ...

class View(QtGui.QWidget):
    def__init__(self):
    super(View, self).__init__()
    ...
    self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Open")
    ...
    self.button.clicked.connect(Model().openFile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = View()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So when I click the "open" button, I want to call the `Model` class' `openFile` method, but when I do click it, it goes into the `Model.__init__` but it never actually goes into the `openFile` method. What do I have to fix?

---

Edit1: Fixed all mistakes.

---

Edit2: For those facing similar issues, here is the solution that Fred S provided and the fixed code.

```
class Model(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.openDir = '/some/file/dir/'
    def openFile(self):
        openFileName = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File",self.openDir,"AllFiles(*.*)")
        openFile = open(openFileName, 'r')
        ...

class View(QtGui.QWidget):
    def__init__(self):
    super(View, self).__init__()
    ...
    self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Open")
    ...
    self.model = Model()
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.model.openFile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = View()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't have PyQt4 on my machine, but I have PySide.  Here's what I see when I run the code:

1) `super(Model, self).__init__(parent)` crashes.   "parent" is not defined.

2) `open = open(openFileName, 'r')` is very bad.  You're redefining a built-in.

3) `self.loadDir` doesn't seem to exist.

4) But as to your question, if I change

```
self.button.clicked.connect(Model().openFile)
```

to be:

```
self.model = Model()
self.button.clicked.connect(self.model.openFile)
```

Then the problem seems fixed.  But this is in PySide, so possibly not in PyQt4.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Fred! I'll try it once I get back to my machine. As per your notes: 1) Oops, I was transcribing and forgot to omit parent. It should be `super(Model, self).__init__()` 2) Typo sorry, it's supposed to be `openFile = open(openFileName, 'r')` 3) `self.loadDir == self.openDir` 4) I vaguely remember trying this as well but I'll know for sure when I get back to my machine. I changed all of these in my original question.

Comment: Thanks Fred! That worked like charm :) Could you maybe explain to me why self.model.openFile works but Model().openFile doesn't work? Is it because you have to initialize the instance first?

Comment: LOL I wish I knew how to figure this out without trial and error.  I have been using pyside for over a year now and I am still finding weird glitches that I can't explain.  And weird differences between it and PyQt4.

Comment: That's really strange... Hmm... Maybe I'll do a little bit more research :)